# Why are all my ASP.NET element references undefined?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

For some reasons I don't know all the elements references in my .aspx.cs are undefined. For example:
In MyPage.aspx I have `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />` and in MyPage.aspx.cs I do `UserName.Text="abc"`. Then after building I get an error that sais: `The name 'UserName' does not exist in the current context`.

[image]

Even in my Global.asax I get an error that sais the characters are not recognized:
[image]

I really don't know what it is, maybe something with my namespaces or something like that. But as I see - all the namespaces are correct.
How can I solve those errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've added some of the *.aspx and *.ascx files from another project, check that the build action of the *.aspx.designer.cs and *.aspx.cs files are set to compile.

Comment: @Naor click on the file in the solution explorer and check the properties. you'll be able to change its build action to compile.

Comment: @Naor right now from your screenshot global.asax is select, if you click on the properties windows, you'll see the options.

Comment: Thanks! I just notice the designer file didn't attached to the project.. Do you know any way to attach all the designer files automatically (I have many)?

Comment: @Naor when adding existing items its best to use the options the IDE provides. right click project -> Add -> Existing item . this will let u add any existing file(s) you have and they will have the right options.